# Dúvida REST - POST

Tags: c#, react, axios

Gostaria de saber se é possível após a resolução da promise de um POST se consigo pegar o resultado e transformar em um array

Ex:

```
axios.post(http://localhost:5000/api/horario/,{
      Nome: nome,
      Horario: horario
    })
```

Gostaria de pegar esses dados e transformar em um array, é possível?

Comment: Queres pegar nesses dados no servidor ou no cliente? Se for no cliente o Axios retorna uma promise, então podes fazer `.then(res => console.log(res));`. É isso que procuras?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Obrigado

Comment: Ok, testaste então juntar `.then(res => console.log(res));` ao código da pergunta? funcionou como querias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questão resvolida no comentario pelo Sergio:

Queres pegar nesses dados no servidor ou no cliente? Se for no cliente o Axios retorna uma promise, então podes fazer .then(res => console.log(res));. É isso que procuras

Answer (score 0):

As promises funcionam com retorno de sucesso e erro, assim como chamadas ajax.

Dessa maneira, você pode executar suas promises da seguinte maneira:

```
axios
.post(url_da_api, objeto_postado)
.then(function(data) {
   // Código a ser executado no retorno do post, em caso de sucesso
   })
.catch(function(error) {
   // Código a ser executado no retorno do post, em caso de erro
   });
```

Recomendo a leitura [deste documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) de especificação para promise!